# How do I run portable versions of apps on Linux?

Tags: firefox

Sometimes I just want to try a software out without installing it onto my system. For example, I downloaded the BlueGriffen software from [here](http://bluegriffon.org/pages/Download)

When I extract the tar.bz2 file, I have the bluegriffen folder with all the files. I am unsure which file to double click.

I've tried double clicking on

bluegriffon
bluegriffon-bin
run-mozilla.sh

But there's no loading of the program. This is a very similar situation for when I download and want to try the latest firefox.

The only program that has ever worked fine without installation is the The Blender program

How do I run software such as firefox and bluegriffen, which I download as archives and extracted, without having to install them?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it is the proper way : once downloaded and unpacked (right click : extract) and remember where you extracted

then from terminal go to that directory : cd dir (to see all the directories inside) then cd 'name of directory'

once you are in the right directory : ./ bluegriffon